# JQuery UI Autocomplete on more than 1 field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI Autocomplete. I have 2 fields that I want the autocomplete to work on. How would i refactor the below so I can have the autocomplete work on 2 fields? I know I can copy and paste the code, but I know theres a better way!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
  jQuery(function() {     
      jQuery( "#wpsc_checkout_form_22" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          var suburb = jQuery("#wpsc_checkout_form_22").val();
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              featureClass: "P",
              style: "full",
              maxRows: 12,
              action: "get_suburb_list",
              query: suburb,                       
            },
            success: function( data ) {
              response( jQuery.map( data.locations, function( item ) {
                return {
                  label: item.location + " " + item.state + " " + item.postcode,                                    
                  value: item.location + " " + item.state + " " + item.postcode
                }
              }));
            }
          });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          //
        },
        open: function() {
          jQuery( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
          jQuery( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: did you try changing the selector from `#wpsc_checkout_form_22` to a class for things that need auto complete?

Comment: No I didnt try that- although I'm not wanting to add a class to the existing html

Comment: You'll need to find some criteria for the selector then. You can always just add another ID to it as in `$("#id1, #id2")`.